# How can I test my production environment instead of my test environment Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling with a problem for a few days right now and I want to know how I can force my Rails app to run in environment and then I want to be able to test the images to ensure that they are http or https.

I'm getting closer and closer to solving the problem but now I want to test my production site instead of my test. The reason being is that when I run my rake tests to check to see if the images have either http or https, it only gives me a relative link such as

```
/images/9995/0007/company_logo.png
```

This is not helpful to me at all. In order to assert_match /http:/ patten, I need it to grab the images on the production site not in test. How can I do this? I've been researching this for a very long while now and I still feel that I'm no where close to figuring this out.

I've tried to force the Rails environment into production by placing this line of code into config/environments.rb

```
ENV["RAILS ENV"] ||= 'production'
```

THe problem is, when I run my tests, doesn't it still refer to the test database? How do I know that when I run rake test TEST=test/functional/ect_test.rb its running production?

I've also tried to have my database.yml file to "point" to production but I made a huge mess of this and to quite frankly I don't really know how that works (It was a recommendation from another stack overflow site). Anyways, some help would be greatly appreciated.

*FYI I am running on Rails 2.3. We are in the middle of upgrading our database. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of starting your server or running your tests with the environment set to `production`. To do this just prepend `RAILS_ENV=production` to the commands `rails server` or `rake test` or whatever you run you server or tests with. The line:

```
ENV["RAILS ENV"] ||= 'production'
```

Is misspelled (just mentioning in case). There's an underscore missing in it. Also, it won't set the `RAILS_ENV` to production if that ENV value is already set. Make it:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'production'
```

To ensure you overwrite any value. Although the aforementioned command prepend technique should work.

**Also, if your site runs in https you can be sure the images with relative paths will be served via https as well.**

Comment: Thanks for your help diego.greyrobot. I appreciate it!